# How to Split Chr data based on | and make new entry for every word

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have data in which one column is genre(chr) in that, values are like "Drama | Musical | Crime", I need to split this data and need to make new row for every entry, like in this value there are 3 values so I need to make three entries with all column in that Data Frame.

```
   imdbId <- "tt0118578"
   title <-"Albela"
   releaseYear<- 2010
   releaseDate  <- "2-12-2010"
   genre <- "Adventure | Drama | Musical"
   writers <- "Ashutosh Gowariker (story) | Ashutosh Gowariker (screenplay) | 
   Kumar Dave (screenplay) | Sanjay Dayma (screenplay) | K.P. Saxena 
   (dialogue)"
   actors <-"Aamir Khan | Gracy Singh | Rachel Shelley | Paul Blackthorne"
   directors<-"Ashutosh Gowariker"
   sequel <-"No"
   hitFlop <-2
   df <- data.frame(imdbId, title,  releaseYear,    releaseDate,    genre,   
   writers, actors, directors,  sequel, hitFlop
    , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)**
```

This is the str of data frame now in this I need to split data and make unique entry for each film based on single genre value.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Adding to what @RalfStubner said, could you provide some of the code that you tried and also the libraries that are you using? that would help us to give you an answer more quickly.

Comment: why is the second "Adventure Drama" should be only drama???

Comment: I'm new to R and on Stackoverflow also, I tried couples of thing, BollywoodMovieDetail %>% separate(BollywoodMovieDetail$genre, c("genre_1", "genre_2", "genre_3"), "| ", extra = "merge"), though it will seprate the data in 3 different column.

Comment: Yes the secound one should be drama only

Comment: I am not even sure how your dataframe looks like? can you please convert your data into a dataframe and then show

Comment: Yes i just did that

Comment: wow what a waste of time my answer was :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

data:

```
multiChar<-
"tt0169102
Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India
2001
08 May 2002
Adventure | Drama | Musical
Ashutosh Gowariker (story) | Ashutosh Gowariker (screenplay) | Kumar Dave (screenplay) | Sanjay Dayma (screenplay) | K.P. Saxena (dialogue)
Aamir Khan | Gracy Singh | Rachel Shelley | Paul Blackthorne
Ashutosh Gowariker
0
6"
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)
patterni <- "(?i)(?<=\\n).*(adventure|drama|musical)(\\s+?(\\|)?\\s+?).*(?=\\n)"

getGenres<- stringr::str_extract(multiChar, patterni) %>%
    str_split("\\|",simplify = T) %>% c %>% trimws

result <- purrr::map(getGenres,~sub(patterni,.,multiChar,perl=T))
```

result:

```
lapply(result,cat)
```

**please note:**

You probably have to come up with a more precise pattern `patterni`.

This here takes the 5th ROW (genre Row). If your genre is always in the 5th row that's your pattern.

```
patterni <- "^(.*?\\n){4}.*(?=\\n)"
getGenres<- stringr::str_extract(multiChar, patterni) %>% sub(".*\\n","",.) %>%
    str_split("\\|",simplify = T) %>% c %>% trimws
```

Comment: Thanks Andre yes it did work for this case but I have data set of around 1880 rows and in each row we have different number of genre values separated by |. but Thanks for your effort really appreciate.

Comment: see my code in the end. I can not give you a solution fitting all data! (because I dont know your data, 2 takes alot of time) But this should lead you to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a question is easy ... if the question is well framed. No code is supplied, so let's assume a dataframe:

```
title <- "Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India"
year <- 2001
genre <- "Adventure | Drama | Musical"
df <- data.frame(title, year, genre, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Add or duplicate as many rows as are required. Then replace the values in the genre column as appropriate.

For a single vector of genre names:

```
genres <- strsplit(df$genre, " \\| ")[[1]]
```

For a list of vectors of genre names:

```
genres <- strsplit(df$genre, " \\| ")
```

Comment: Yes my bad, but please bear with me will improve in coming days on how to frame question so that it is clear to all.

Comment: I have edit the question, have a look it might help.

Comment: Deepanshu, the purpose of SO is to answer a specific code question, not to pose a development question asking others to develop for you. Please run your code before you post it.  The code snippet supplied does not run.

Comment: (1) Terminating a line with ``**`` throws an EOF error. (2) In some cases, lines ending in a `,` can be continued on the next line. A line cannot start with a `,`. (3) The writers string has an imbedded CR/LF; do you intend that?

Answer (score 0):

I  created a function that uses stringr to split a column, given the pattern and a name prefix for the generated column.

```
    **split_into_multiple <- function(column, pattern = ", ", into_prefix){
    cols <- str_split_fixed(column, pattern, n = Inf)
    # Sub out the ""'s returned by filling the matrix to the right, with NAs which 
    are useful
    cols[which(cols == "")] <- NA
    cols <- as.tibble(cols)
    # name the 'cols' tibble as 'into_prefix_1', 'into_prefix_2', ..., 
    'into_prefix_m' 
    # where m = # columns of 'cols'
    m <- dim(cols)[2]
    names(cols) <- paste(into_prefix, 1:m, sep = "_")
    return(cols)
    }**
```

We can then use split_into_multiple in a dplyr pipe as follows:

```
    **after <- BollywoodMovieDetail %>% 
    bind_cols(split_into_multiple(.$genre,"\\|", "genre")) %>% 
    # selecting those that start with 'genre_' will remove the original 'genre' column
    select(imdbId, starts_with("genre_"))
    > after
    # A tibble: 1,284 x 4
    imdbId    genre_1      genre_2     genre_3   
    <chr>     <chr>        <chr>       <chr>     
    1 tt0118578 Romance      NA          NA        
    2 tt0169102 "Adventure " " Drama "   " Musical"
    3 tt0187279 "Action "    " Comedy"   NA        
    4 tt0222024 "Drama "     " Romance"  NA        

    # ... with 1,274 more rows**
```

And then we can use gather to tidy up...

```
    **> after %>% 
    +     gather(key, val, -imdbId, na.rm = T)
    A tibble: 2,826 x 3
   imdbId    key     val         
  * <chr>     <chr>   <chr>       
  1 tt0118578 genre_1 Romance     
  2 tt0169102 genre_1 "Adventure "
  3 tt0187279 genre_1 "Action "   
  4 tt0222024 genre_1 "Drama "    
  5 tt0227194 genre_1 "Action "   

  # ... with 2,816 more rows**
```